# XAMPP keeping old data in memory?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm not sure what's going on here. Here's how I can best describe this...

1. Imagine that I have a simple login form. If the user does not input a password they will get echo "Missing Password Information".

Now let's say that I decide that I want to change the message to "Please enter your password". I re-save my file. But when I run the file it still triggers the old error message, even though that message has been updated.

2. Then I've had times where I refer to some code in another file. Then I realize that I will just put that code in the same file that's calling for it. I update everything and re-save and for some reason it still pulls back old data from the old file, which I deleted and killed all connections to.
3. Or sometimes it freaks out, because it's looking for a file that I deleted. What's weird is I'll update my other pages and code within those pages so that they don't require that old file at all. They literally should have no knowledge of that old file nor require it.
4. Then I noticed something strange with a syntax error that should have thrown an error. So I tested this and created just one, single test.php file and put this in it...

echo "Test"

It didn't display "Test" as you can imagine, but it didn't even complain about the missing semi-colon. But then other times it will show error messages. It's all over the place.

So I've backed up my htdocs folder, completely uninstalled XAMPP, turned off my anti-virus and reinstalled XAMPP. This works for a while and then it starts behaving badly again. I've reinstalled the latest version of XAMPP at least 4 times now.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And what happens when you refresh the page with CTRL-F5, does it still happen

Comment: why don't you try MAMP?

Comment: Yeah...I'll refresh the page and it still does it. Actually I have one piece of code that has an error for the user. I decided to comment out this bit of code, and when I run the script it's still delivering the error message in the code that is completely commented out with /* */ - weird. I'm more familiar with XAMPP - I guess that's why I haven't tried MAMP yet, but I'll have to check it out.